# how to only target a css class if it is the first element within the body tag?

Tags: css

How can I target a element with a class only if it is the first element under the body tag, and then not style any other elements with the same class on the same page?

Comment: Sure, you can! Any other questions? Have you tried anything?

Comment: At least share your thoughts. Tell step by step, out loud what you want to accomplish. You would be surprised how declarative `js`, or `css` can be can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target an element as direct child of the `body` only if it's *both* the first-child and with a specific class name

```
body > .yourclass:first-child {
   ...
}
```

`:first-child` matches a specific element, regardless of its class name but in this case the class must be also chained. All other elements with that class name won't be styled.

---

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWNOMZ)